# Multiple pages per sheet (PDF)

Tags: pdf, ps, ghostscript

I use the following [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) commands

```
pdf2ps input.pdf - | psnup -pA4 -4 >> output.ps
ps2pdf output.ps output.pdf
rm output.ps
```

to merge multiple pages (in this case 4) from input file to one sheet in outupt file.

How can I modify pipelining so that I won't have to use 2 commands, but just a single one liner? Is there any other commandline tool that would do the same and can work directly on pdf files?

Comment: First part of question is solved - I used:
pdf2ps input.pdf - | psnup -pA4 -4 | ps2pdfwr - >> output.pdf


How about second part? I still convert pdf to ps and than again back... Can this be optimisied?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [PDFjam](http://go.warwick.ac.uk/pdfjam) that brings `pdfnup` and allows you to do basically the same things as `psnup`.

Comment: thanks! that's much better as it already comes as dependency of other pdf applications and it's even installed in our school computer pools :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: For anyone wondering - the resulting command is:
pdfnup --nup 2x2 --suffix '2x2' Dokumente/input.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I love pdftk, a quick search on google will lead you to it. There is a cmdline for linux,  and a gui for windows and a usb portable version for windows. Pretty slick.